# Ruby on rails unique token for every ticket

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a cinema cite, that everybody can see movies and get their own tickets.
I got two problems:

1. I want to give every ticket unique code that will be send to email after customer will reserve ticket. How to make unique code in ruby on rails.
2. I got tables `customer(name,surname,email)` and `ticket(type,numberofseats,seance_id,customer_id)` and in method `ticket#new` i also want to make `customer`, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the unique token, make sure you have a `token` field in your `Ticket` model:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :generate_token

  protected
  def generate_token
    self.token = loop do
      random_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
      break random_token unless Ticket.exists?(token: random_token)
    end
  end
end
```

To make new `customer` in `ticket#new`:

```
def new
  @ticket = Ticket.new
  @customer = Customer.new
end
```

and in your `ticket#create` action, you need to create the customer first with `params[:customer]` and then create the ticket with `params[:ticket]` and the `customer_id` where you got from the customer you just created.

Comment: what datatype in table should have this token?

Comment: Just use `string` for `token`

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is generate a Unique id by the time he did the order + his customer number. The chance that a customer order more tickets at the exact same time is kinda nil.

Comment: Default rails framework add to table id of ticket but in order 1,2,3... i prefer some unique code

Comment: I understand. If you take the ticket_id and add the current Unix timestamp and the customer number you get something Unique

Comment: FWIW this is a [compound key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) and most DBAs would prefer it. If you're still insisting on a UUID fine, but realize if you're thinking of using either of these vs. the Rails convention of an autoincrementing ID column that its going to get complicated quick, i.e. you'll always be fighting the framework and UUID is prob YAGNI. You might want to investigate [ROM](https://github.com/rom-rb/rom) if you go that way. I'd advise against datamapper.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looking for just unique token. I'd rather use Time based approach. For not much-frequent requests (max one per second). You can use

```
Time.now.to_i
```

To get it in string `Time.now.to_i.to_s`
If you are dealing with frequent requests (thousands per second) while generating token. Use float conversation

```
Time.now.to_f #1532415770.0032046
```

To get it in string you can use `Time.now.to_f.to_s.gsub(".", "")` although not recommended.

The chance of repentance of above value is close to null in current universe.